# Strange TypeException errors in Account triggers

Tags: trigger, exception

I have a very basic trigger that once particular object is updated serializes it to JSON (all fields) and posts to external web service. (This trigger is installed on the organization via  managed package)

Recently I found an issue with this trigger that I can reproduce on my "full sandbox" organization but not on my test and development orgs.

When I try to update and Account object I get following exception

```
System.TypeException: Data type not supported (Namespace)
```

Where *Namespace* is a namespace of my managed package. I think it is caused by some special rules or fields on Account object - but I am not sure how to fix this issue as I do not see such type of error ("Data Tpe not supported") in Salesforce docs